# Coloring Legend Labels for Bar Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I'm trying to build a chart of Champions League Winners and their domestic league finishes. I found the best to way to color each bar by team was to loop through each season/year and add a bar plot for each like below.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(16,8)
for s in P_df['Season']:
    x = s
    y = P_df.loc[P_df['Season'] == s, 'Position']
    y = y.to_list()[0]
    team = P_df.loc[P_df['Season'] == s, 'Team']
    team = team.to_list()[0]
    face = color_key[team]
    edge = color2nd_key[team]
    ax.bar(x,y,color=face,label=team,edgecolor =edge,linewidth =3)
```

When I try to add a legend, it includes all teams including repeats, so I tried to feed it just the unique teams (to avoid repeats) and then loop through the legend labels and assign the colors that way in the code below:

```
ax.legend(color_key,loc = 'upper right')
leg = ax.legend(P_df['Team'].unique(),bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0, facecolor = 'black',edgecolor ='white')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
la = set(labels)
la = list(la)
for label in la:
    for ha in ax.legend_.legendHandles:
        te = label
        e = color2nd_key[te]
        f = color_key[te]
        ha.set_edgecolor(e)
        ha.set_facecolor(f)
```

Only issue is when I do this it assigns the colors of what I assume is the first value is the list to all of the legend labels as shown in the linked picture below.
[legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4jUG.png)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update was able to do this and it worked:

```
for team1 in P_df['Team'].unique():
    e = color2nd_key[team1]
    f = color_key[team1]
    patch = mpatches.Patch(edgecolor =e, facecolor =f, label = team1)
    patches.append(patch)
leg = ax.legend(labels,handles = patches,bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0, facecolor = 'tan',edgecolor ='white')
```